# Prevent caching of index.html in React spa application

Tags: reactjs, .net, iis, webserver, browser-cache

I am using `React` as frontend and `.net` framework with `IIS` web server as backend development technology. I tried several ways to prevent caching `index.html` file by IIS but they didn't work as expected and `index.html` file still is serving from disk cache.
Here is the steps that i followed:

#### Added meta tags to the `index.html`:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

#### Added rules in `web.config` file of the web server:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <location path="index.html">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>

</configuration>
```

No one of the above worked for me. Any idea why?

*thanks for the responses...*

Comment: Does this problem occur in a particular browser or is it the same for all browsers?

Comment: @omidpayandeh Mozilla does not prevent of caching and it uses disk cache instead of revalidation the file.

Answer (score 0):

could try below code to prevent caching:

```
<location path="index.html">
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Comment: I have tried this solution and it works in Chrome perfectly well but Mozilla still caches the `index.html` file and prevent of revalidating it. Any idea?

Comment: @AliBayatMokhtari after knowing you are only facing this issue in FF i made test . here is you can try for FF to prevent caching "<customHeaders>
                    <add name="cache-control" value="no-store" />
                </customHeaders>"

Comment: here is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpVPc.png)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. My IIS web server version is 10 (we have to support IIS 6 and later) and the FF version is 112 (mac os). BTW thanks for spending time.

Comment: Hi @AliBayatMokhtari, how your issue got fixed ? Could you please update your answer here